# Create new hasMany children from parent controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have two controllers "Events" and "Activities" and both have many "Attendees".

```
$this->hasMany('Attendees')
    ->setClassName('Attendees')
    ->setForeignKey('foreign_id')
    ->setConditions(array('Attendees.class' => 'Activity'))
    ->setDependent(true);
```

[image]

I am using a class and a foreign_id in my Attendees table to link them. I would like to create addAttendee() function in my ActivitiesController for example to add a new attendee, but I am not sure how to proceed.

```
public function addAttendee($id = null)
{
    $activity = $this->Activities->get($id, ['contain' => ['Venues', 'Contacts']]);

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        ??
    }

    $this->set(compact('activity'));
}
```

I found some documentation on saving with association but not on creating new association.

Comment: To start with, you'll need to make sure that the save strategy for the association is `append`, not `replace`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new `Attendee` entity then link it to your `$activity`.

```
$data = ['first_name' => 'blah', 'last_name' => ... fields]);
$attendee = $this->Attendee->newEntity($data);

$this->Attendee->link($activity, [$attendee]);
```

source: https://api.cakephp.org/4.2/class-Cake.ORM.Association.HasMany.html#link()

Comment: Thanks. But I would like to use a form to create the attendee. So I used loadmodel() below but not sure if it's the right way to proceed.

Comment: What does your `$this->request->getData()` look like? If you have a `attendees` key and your fields are following convention, then cake should automatically save the association.

Comment: FUN fact: if you have an `hasMany` association defined you don't need to load the Model. You can just call `$this->Activities->Attendees`.

Comment: My getData() is an array :^ array:10 [▼
  "title" => "Mr"
  "firstname" => "John"
  "lastname" => "Doe"
  "address" => "address"
  "city" => "city"
  "zipcode" => "xxxx"
  "country" => "Country"
  "email" => "john@doe.com"
  "phone" => "xxxxxxxxx"
  "payment_method" => "xxxxxx"
]

Comment: Hmm. yeah try saying with an `attendees` key. https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations

Answer (score 0):

I proceed this way. It's working but not sure if it's the right way to proceed ??

```
public function addAttendee($id)
{
    $activity = $this->Activities->get($id, ['contain' => ['Venues', 'Contacts']]);
    $attendee = $this->Activities->Attendees->newEmptyEntity();

    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        $attendee = $this->Activities->Attendees->patchEntity($attendee, $this->request->getData() + ['class' => 'retreat', 'foreign_id' => $id]);

        if ($this->Activities->Attendees->save($attendee))
        {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The attendee has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view', $id]);
        }

        $this->Flash->error(__('The attendee could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }

    $this->set(compact('activity', 'attendee'));
}
```